# Get column name from Linq to Sql Entity

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am new to linq to sql. Wondering if I can get the name of the column. Like First_Name, Last_name instead of 'Peter',  'Parker'.

My Code is like:

```
using (DataContext context = new DataContext(ConnectionString))
{
    var results = (from person in context.Persons
                   select person);

     foreach (Person person in results.ToList<Persons>())
     {
            //Here I need the Column name of the person.FirstName
     }
}
```

Comment: Column name of person.FirstName is "FirstName"?

Comment: @CuongLe Couldn't that be change with mapping or annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var column = typeof(Person).GetProperty("FirstName")
    .GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ColumnAttribute, false)
        as ColumnAttribute;

var name = column.Name;
```

See the [ColumnAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.aspx);