# is there a way to use linq2sql context as datasource

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, data-binding

I am trying to databind a database table with two columns to a combobox, can this be done with linq2sql/dbml?  Seems like it should be possible, but I can't find an object property to assign as the DataMember, even trying the reflection tricks mentioned in other posts.

```
var itemslist = from items in dbcontext.itemslisttable select items;
comboBox1.DataSource = itemslist;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = ???
```

something like

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = itemslist.ItemDescriptionColumn.Name;
```

or

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = itemslist.First().ItemDescriptionColumn.Name;
```

am I way off here, should I just use a string literal and be done with it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12507824/832705 is one type reflection approach that requires the column name literal

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you should be able to use LINQtoSQL/dbl context class as a datasource for your combo box.**

A little information about the combobox:

- The **DisplayMember** of a Combobox gets or sets a string that specifies the property of the data source whose contents you want to display.
- The **ValueMember** property also gets or sets a string; it determines which value gets moved into the SelectedValue of the Combo Box.

```cs
var itemslist = from items in dbContext.itemslisttable
            select items;

comboBox1.DataSource = itemslist;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"; 
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ProductID";
```

Comment: that is a helpful reminder about the ValueMember property, I was looking for a strongly typed string column name, 1.25 extro hrs later, I found a solution using an anonymous new datatable with just the one column, then using GetType() and GetProperties() to pull the column name from the one returned PropertyInfo

Comment: @stackuser83 your question was if you can use linq2sql as a datasource. I got the impression that you did not know how to set the DisplayMember property from your examples. It was not clear that you wanted to set with a strongly typed value.

Comment: you are right, my question is poorly pointed, the solution I mention above is probably a weak hackaround, but will do for use, thank you for your help